# How to Disable the Check for Server Certificate Revocation in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, https, ocsp

In my wp8 app,

1. I enter a **open wifi** which is operated by communication operator
2. blocked by a portal page that needs using account and password to log in
3. after I **post** some data to a **https url**
4. I have the ability to use the wifi network to access to internet freely.

Now,I encounter a problem:
before the https connection established successfully,it will be running the **Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)**
OCSP needs to access to CA like veriSign to verify the server certificate status

> *but I have no internet access at this moment.*

So,my app return a Webexception whose description is "**The remote server returned an error: NotFound**".I think it is because of the failure of OCSP.
Based on above,I want to find a solution to sovle this:

1. **My point** is to disable the OCSP mechanism，Do you know how to do this?
2. And I also would like to know **if there is another solution** to sovle the problem.

Hope your advice,Thanks!

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/249525/google_chrome_will_no_longer_check_for_revoked_ssl_certificates_online.html

Comment: above is to make the case more clear to understand

Comment: Can you use an http connection first, say to a webservice that simply returns "OK", to trigger whatever it is that establishes an internet connection before performing https operation?

Answer (score 1):

The way you'd do that on .NET is to set the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` delegate and perform the logic you want to perform.  But, unfortunately that is not yet available on Windows Phone.

There are various uservoice suggestions related to this, for example:

- http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2146033-allow-self-signed-and-corporate-certificates-for-s
- http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4299617-client-ssl-certificate-authentication

They don't apply to you directly, but if they end up gaining access to ServicePointManager then you'll be able to do what you want to do.